# GET the excerpt by ID

Tags: posts, excerpt

Why is it that one cannot get the excerpt by ID like with the title and most other elements.

eg. get_the_excerpt(ID). I know how to use it with the $post->post_excerpt function but that does not return part of the content if no excerpt was entered it simple returns nothing.

So what I am trying to do is get the excerpt by ID if there is an excerpt, and if there isn't an excerpt with that ID but there is some content, to get some of the content instead.

How would one do that.

Any ideas,

Marvellous ...

EDIT --

Loop Source Code as Requested.

```
<?php $stories = get_posts('category_name=feedback&numberposts=4'); 
            foreach ($stories as $post) :
            $title = $post->post_title;
            $excerpt = get_the_excerpt_id($post->ID);
            $thumb = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID,array(60, 60, true));?>
              <div class="textstandard_white" style="font-size:14px; line-height:22px; padding-top:10px;"><b><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>"><?php echo $title;?></a></b></div><div align="left" style="height:18px; width:82px; background:url(http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/structure/icons/stars.png) left top no-repeat;"><div id="stars<?php echo $post->ID;?>" align="left" style="height:18px; background:url(http://www.divethegap.com/update/z-images/structure/icons/stars_glow.png) left top no-repeat;">
                  </div>
                  </div>

                  <script type="text/javascript">
                var width<?php echo $post->ID;?> = ((<?php
$Rating = get_post_meta($post->ID, "Rating", true);
echo $Rating;
?> * 20) + '%')
                  $('#stars<?php echo $post->ID;?>').css('width', width<?php echo $post->ID;?>);

                 </script><div class="textstandard_white" style="padding-top:6px; font-size:10px; color:#BBB; padding-bottom:10px; border-bottom:1px dotted #BBB; min-height:70px;"><div style="float:left; padding-right:6px; padding-bottom:6px;"><div style="background:#FFF; border:1px solid #FFF;
border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px ; -webkit-border-radius: 4px; padding:4px;"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID);?>"><?php echo $thumb;?></a></div></div>



<?php echo $excerpt;?></div>
              <?php endforeach;?>
```

Comment: what exactly is "some" of the content?

Comment: The excerpt function in wordpress returns the excerpt of a post. If the post does not have an excerpt it returns a certain number of characters of the content followed by '...' or 'read more' or whatever the template provides

Comment: Not to be a PITA but community rules disallow signatures and standard closings. So as to abide by the rules and avoid having [Jeff Atwood](http://stackexchange.com/about/management) send you a stern message after editing all your questions, please stop using *"Marvellous"* as a closing. *(And please don't shoot the messenger)*

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Hi **@Robin I. Knight:**

I view `get_the_excerpt()` as a function with legacy design. As WordPress usage has grown there are many newer use-cases where it doesn't fit but where the newer functions for getting different data do. One example is the now frequent use of an `$args` array of function options.

But it's easy to fix for your needs. Here's an alternative function you can use which you can put anywhere in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function robins_get_the_excerpt($post_id) {
  global $post;  
  $save_post = $post;
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  $output = get_the_excerpt();
  $post = $save_post;
  return $output;
}
```

I've not tested it but am pretty sure I got it right. If this doesn't meet your needs please elaborate and maybe I can make other suggestions.

Comment: It works. Sort of. Very odd results. It is definitely performing its function but the results are odd. I am using it in conjunction with GET_Posts and for some reason the top 2 get posts are always the same. Here is a link and you will see what I mean. Look at the 4 posts on the right hand side. http://www.divethegap.com/update/community/feedback/2010/06/steve-riches/

Comment: @Robin I Knight: Please post your loop source code as an update to your question; it's very hard to debug code without seeing code. It's also possibly a plugin that is causing the problem; try disabling them one at a time.

Comment: Loop source code in question above ^^

Comment: BTW I changed the name of the function to get_the_excerpt_id($post_id)

Comment: @Robin I Knight - I don't see anything in your loop, but you might try calling `setup_postdata($post)` at the beginning of your loop, as @Rarst suggests. If that doesn't work it might be a plugin you need to disable; have you tried that?  And you probably don't want to call it `get_the_excerpt_id()` because WordPress could add that function in the future and break your site. And you could probably do without the function in your loop by using `foreach($stories as $story): global $post; $post = $story;` instead.

Answer (score 16):

The mechanics of excerpt are extremely confusing. It is not precise answer to your question but in general if you need to make template tags, specific to Loop, work with array returned by `get_posts()` you can emulate Loop like this:

```
$stories = get_posts(); 

foreach ($stories as $post) {

    setup_postdata($post);

    // stuff
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: what about wp_reset_query(); ?

Comment: @cwd if only using `setup_postdata()` global query is not affected and only post data needs to be reset.

Comment: This solution is allot cleaner than storing the post in another var and requering another post just to get it global. +1

Comment: Thanks @Rarst that helped me out. Adding setup_postdata($post); resolved my issues

Answer (score 9):

There is a new function since 3.3.0: [wp_trim_words](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)

I'm using it outside the loop as follows:

```
 <?php if ( $post_id ) {
 $post = get_post( $post_id );
 if ( $post ) { ?>
     <h2><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></h2>
     <p><em><?php echo wp_trim_words( $post->post_content ); ?></em></p>
     <p><strong>This article can only be read by subscribers.</strong></p>
 <?php } } ?>
```

This is not to be confused with [wp_trim_excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_excerpt) that apparently only works within the loop, since it calls the_content() internally.

Answer (score 6):

Just to add to MikeSchinkel's answer, which for some reason wouldn't work for me. I had to add the setup_postdata line to make it work.

```
function get_the_excerpt( $post_id ){

  global $post;  
  $save_post = $post;
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  setup_postdata( $post ); // hello
  $output = get_the_excerpt();
  $post = $save_post;
  return $output;
```

}

I'm assuming if you're using this outside the loop then it shouldn't interfere with other setup_postdata going on.

Cheers

Comment: I tried MikeSchinkel's answer and it did not work for me. Setting up post data did the trick. In my case without the 'setup_postdata' the function returned the title+excerpt of the parent post.

Answer (score 2):

Building on @Maxime's answer, would this work?

```
$post = get_post( $id );

$excerpt = ( $post->post_excerpt ) ? $post->post_excerpt : $post->post_content;
```

It seems straight forward enough to me, but I'm wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If **ALL** your posts have the `<!--more-->` tag, then you can use the following with your code above:

```
$sjc_excerpt = explode( '<!--more-->', $post->post_content); 
echo wpautop( $sjc_excerpt[0] );
```

Of course if you have any posts that don't have the `<!--more-->` tag, they'll be shown in their entirety. Works in my situation, but not for all...

Answer (score 1):

I view `get_the_excerpt()` as a function with legacy design. As WordPress usage has grown there are many newer use-cases where it doesn't fit but where the newer functions for getting different data do. One example is the now frequent use of an `$args` array of function options.

But it's easy to fix for your needs. Here's an alternative function you can use which you can put anywhere in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
function robins_get_the_excerpt($post_id) {
   global $post;  
   $save_post = $post;
   $post = get_post($post_id);
   $output = get_the_excerpt();
   $post = $save_post;
   return $output;
}
```

Just to add to MikeSchinkel's answer, which for some reason wouldn't work for me. I had to add the setup_postdata line to make it work.

Comment: Does this need `wp_reset_post_data()` to work inside the loop?

Comment: Apparently (after going around this particular house) it's now part of core.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little two-liner I use a lot utilizing **[wp_trim_words](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)**.  I constantly finding myself needing the abbreviation and read more functionalities outside of the loop.  Some one else may find this useful. So this is what I use to:

1. Get the Excerpt by POST ID
2. Get Post Content If no Excerpt has been set,
3. Set the Word length of the Excerpt
4. Choose the Content for the Read More(Link/Text)

I put this inline, directly in the custom template I am editing.

```
    //Get Post Object
    $dapost = get_post(POST_ID);              
    //Get the Execerpt
    $my_excerpt = wp_trim_words( apply_filters( "the_excerpt", get_the_excerpt($dapost) ? get_the_excerpt($dapost) : $dapost->post_content  ), "20", "<a href='$dapost->guid'> ".__('Get More Stuff', 'translation')."</a>" );
```

### Break Down

### 1.The excerpt content

Get the Excerpt by Post ID but, get Post Content If no Excerpt has been set.

*I am using If/Else PHP shorthand*.

```
    $dapost = get_post(POST_ID);    
    apply_filters( "the_excerpt", get_the_excerpt($dapost) ? get_the_excerpt($dapost) : $dapost->post_content
```

### 2. Word length

Set the amount of words in the Excerpt to **20**

```
    "20"
```

### 3. Choose ReadMore Content(Link/Text)

```
   "<a href='$dapost->guid'> ".__('Get More Stuff', 'translation')."</a>"
```

I used `$dapost->guid` to get the URL, because I did not need friendly URLs, and wanted to avoid another call to the DB. You could always use get_the_permalink.

See **[wp_trim_words](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words)** in the Wordpress Documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
$excerpt = apply_filters('the_excerpt', get_post_field('post_excerpt', $post_ide));
```

Answer (score 0):

From WP 4.5.0 is possible use the post ID as parameter
`get_the_excerpt( $post->ID )`

Source:https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_excerpt/

Answer (score 0):

As annoying as it can be, it's actually fairly straightforward to do

```
function cameronjonesweb_get_excerpt_by_id( $post_id ) {
    return apply_filters( 'get_the_excerpt', wp_trim_excerpt( '', $post_id ), $post_id );
}
```