# Empty excerpt using wp_get_recent_posts

Tags: excerpt, recent-posts

I have this simple shortcode to display the last posts with it's title and except:

```
add_shortcode('latest3', function(){
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(
            array(
                'numberposts'   => 3,
                'orderby'       => 'post_date',
                'order'         => 'DESC',
                'post_type'     => 'post',
                'post_status'   => 'publish'
            ), ARRAY_A);

    $output = '<h2>Latest posts</h2>';
    foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        $output .= '<h3>'.$recent["post_title"].'</h3>';
        $output .= $recent["post_excerpt"];
    }
    return $output;
});
```

But for some reason the excerpt output is empty. `print_r($recents)` shows that there is indeed an array key called `post_excerpt` but is shown always empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `post_excerpt` value is empty because you have no explicit excerpts for your posts. While `the_excerpt()` does generate an excerpt from the posts content if the post excerpt is empty, the function `wp_get_recent_posts()`, which is basically a wrapper for `get_posts()`, doesn't.

Comment: makes sense. Thought that in this case the excerpt would return the excerpt of the post content itself. Thanks

Comment: My pleasure. I'd say thats what will commonly happen, if you are not that familiar with WP. You might want to take a look at this [Q&A's](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12498/22534) or you do what Tomás Cot [suggested](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/161048/22534). @Th3Alchemist

Answer (score 4):

This code could work, I'm using the `setup_postdata` to create a `post` object similar to what the function `the_post()` does, so now you can use the functions you have in a Loop.

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(
            array(
                'numberposts'   => 3,
                'orderby'       => 'post_date',
                'order'         => 'DESC',
                'post_type'     => 'post',
                'post_status'   => 'publish'
            ), OBJECT);

    $output = '<h2>Latest posts</h2>';
    foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
        setup_postdata($recent);
        $output .= '<h3>'.get_the_title().'</h3>';
        $output .= get_the_excerpt();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;
```

Comment: Better be save than sorry and add `wp_reset_postdata()`

Comment: I don't think it's neccesary in this context, but, yes, it can be added just to be safe.

Comment: Like i said: »better be save than sorry« :)

Comment: It is not neccessary to `setup_postdata($recent)`
You can just use `$recent` in `get_the_tilte($recent)` and `get_the_except($recent)`

Comment: what's the diff between wp_reset_postdata(); and wp_reset_query(); in this case?